# Mouse freezes for Ubuntu 19.04 running VirtualBox

Tags: mouse, virtualization, plasma-5

After working for a few days or so my plasma session does not react to mouse clicks anymore. I can switch to *tty* and I can move the cursors. But I cannot use it anymore.

```
journalctl --boot=-1
```

gives me (this is what happens before i switch to tty to reboot):

```
Mai 15 13:17:01 mf1 CRON[17899]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mai 15 13:30:01 mf1 CRON[17967]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mai 15 13:30:01 mf1 CRON[17968]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Mai 15 13:30:01 mf1 CRON[17967]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mai 15 13:31:54 mf1 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Mai 15 13:31:54 mf1 anacron[18069]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-05-15
Mai 15 13:31:54 mf1 anacron[18069]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Mai 15 13:31:54 mf1 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  64
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Connected"
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  0
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 65535
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  64
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Connected"
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  0
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 64 update
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x564c8ce491d0)
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 66
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 64 : connected = true , enabled = true
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 64 update
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x564c8ce491d0)
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 66
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 64 : connected = true , enabled = true
Mai 15 13:44:00 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(640, 480)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  1
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary Output: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change Screen Size: true
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                 Old: QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                 Intermediate: QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                 New: QSize(640, 480)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Disable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change outputs: true
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                  (64)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Enable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetCrtcConfig (change output)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Output: 64 ( "VGA-1" )
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Pos: QPoint(0,0)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Mode: 822 KScreen::Mode(Id: "822" , Size: QSize(640, 480) @ 59.9375 )
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Rotation: 1
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Result:  0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 64 update
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x564c8ce491d0)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 822
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetScreenSize
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         DPI: 96
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Size: QSize(640, 480)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         SizeMM: QSize(169, 127)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  822
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Geometry:  0 0 640 480
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 65535
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  822
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Geometry:  0 0 640 480
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  640 480
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  169 127
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(640, 480)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  1
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary Output: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change Screen Size: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Disable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Enable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  64
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  822
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Connected"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 23
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  640 480
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  169 127
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputChange
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Output:  64
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  822
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Connection:  "Connected"
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Subpixel Order:  0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 64 update
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x564c8ce491d0)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 822
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 64 : connected = true , enabled = true
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 64 update
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x564c8ce491d0)
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 822
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Mai 15 13:44:01 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 64 : connected = true , enabled = true
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  1
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary Output: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change Screen Size: true
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                 Old: QSize(640, 480)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                 Intermediate: QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                 New: QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Disable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change outputs: true
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:                  (64)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Enable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetScreenSize
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         DPI: 96
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Size: QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         SizeMM: QSize(508, 254)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: RRSetCrtcConfig (change output)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Output: 64 ( "VGA-1" )
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Pos: QPoint(0,0)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Mode: 66 KScreen::Mode(Id: "66" , Size: QSize(1920, 960) @ 59.9947 )
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Rotation: 1
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Result:  0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 64 update
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x564c8ce491d0)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Geometry:  0 0 1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Geometry:  0 0 1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  1
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary Output: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change Screen Size: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Disable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Enable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
Mai 15 13:44:12 mf1 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty2.
Mai 15 13:44:18 mf1 login[1111]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user mafunk by LOGIN(uid=0)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Pos: QPoint(0,0)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Mode: 66 KScreen::Mode(Id: "66" , Size: QSize(1920, 960) @ 59.9947 )
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Rotation: 1
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Result:  0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandROutput 64 update
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_connected: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         m_crtc XRandRCrtc(0x564c8ce491d0)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         CRTC: 63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         MODE: 66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Connection: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary: true
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Geometry:  0 0 1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Geometry:  0 0 1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRScreenChangeNotify
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Window: 48234501
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Root: 701
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size ID: 0
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Size:  1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         SizeMM:  508 254
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_CrtcChange
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         CRTC:  63
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Mode:  66
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Rotation:  "Rotate_0"
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xcb.helper:         Geometry:  0 0 1920 960
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Requested screen size is QSize(1920, 960)
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Needed CRTCs:  1
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Actions to perform:
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Primary Output: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change Screen Size: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Disable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Change outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr:         Enable outputs: false
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: XRandR::setConfig done!
Mai 15 13:44:02 mf1 org.kde.KScreen[1698]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
Mai 15 13:44:12 mf1 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty2.
Mai 15 13:44:18 mf1 login[1111]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user mafunk by LOGIN(uid=0)
Mai 15 13:44:18 mf1 systemd-logind[721]: New session 35 of user mafunk.
Mai 15 13:44:18 mf1 systemd[1]: Started Session 35 of user mafunk.
Mai 15 13:44:33 mf1 sudo[18355]:   mafunk : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/home/mafunk ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/aptitude safe-upgrade
Mai 15 13:44:33 mf1 sudo[18355]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mafunk(uid=0)
Mai 15 13:44:48 mf1 systemd-resolved[667]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mai 15 13:48:23 mf1 useradd[4487]: failed adding user 'vboxadd', data deleted
Mai 15 13:48:23 mf1 useradd[4488]: failed adding user 'vboxadd', data deleted
Mai 15 13:48:24 mf1 kernel: SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
Mai 15 13:48:24 mf1 kernel: JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
Mai 15 13:48:24 mf1 kernel: ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
```

I am not sure if it is related and if so, how. Not sure if anyone can help out here.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

- 2D/3D acceleration is off.
- Vt-d  is enabled.
- Guest additions are installed.
- 'sudo dkms status' -> returns empty
- 'sudo dpkg -l *virtualbox*'

> Blockquote
>   Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
>   | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
>   |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
>   ||/ Name                     Version      Architecture Description
>   +++-========================-============-============-=================================
>   un  virtualbox-guest-modules               (no description available)
>   - $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell does not exist

Comment: please clarify the issue is hapening in a virtual machine? in this case please describe the configuration options for that virtual machine is 2-D and 3-D acceleration off? keep it off. did you enable Vt-d at the BIOS-level? are virtualbox guest aditions installed on the VM and is the host windows?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.